# CORS policy blocking

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть проект в котором нужно настроить авторизацию. При попытке авторизоваться вылазит `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/login?username=admin&password=admin' from origin 'http://localhost:9528' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` Подскажите как от этого избавиться. Вот сам проект [MyProject](https://github.com/alex888508/Example)

Comment: Вопрос звучит так: я сделал ракету, собрал двигатель, корпус, все работает. Как теперь ее запустить?

Comment: Предположу что из-за того что фронт и бэк на разных портах, нужно на бекенде выставить заголовок  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
На боевом проекте соотвественно вместо звёздочки домен вашего фронта

Comment: На бек прописал `('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'`, и на фронте на всякий случай указал `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080/login',`. И все равно не работает

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить @Bean в SpringSecurityConfig. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                ....

@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
```